# Periodic solution of O.DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Given the D.E
> $$
> x''=-9x+2x^3+2[(x')^2]x
> $$
> show that it has a periodic solution and find it.

After polar transformation I get $$2xy(r^2-4)=rr'.$$ I want to solve for $r$. How do get rid off $2xy$

Comment: Could you share details on how you move from the first expression to the second one? This would make the question clearer and more likely to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can continue from your equation as it is separable
$$
\frac{rr'}{r^2-4}=2xx'\implies \ln|r^2-4|=2x^2+c,~~r^2-4=Ce^{2x^2}
$$
This means that
$$
F(x,y)=e^{-2x^2}(x^2+y^2-4)
$$
is a first integral of the equation, $C=F(x,x')$ is constant along any solution. Now it remains to show that the level curves for the solutions of interest are bounded and free of equilibrium points.